# Magento: Checkout scrolling to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

We got a problem that when a next step is loading inside the one page checkout, the page is not scrolling to the top.

If a person enters all their data on the billing step and clicks on the continue button, the next step is loading on half way of the page. Based on the last position in the previous step.

I want that every step inside the one page checkout begins from the top of the page.

I currently got this inside opcheckout.js:

```
gotoSection: function(section)
{
    var sectionElement = $('opc-'+section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-'+section);
    this.reloadProgressBlock(section);
    jQuery("html, body").delay(10).animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#opc-"+section).offset().top }, 500);
},
```

But that does not work well, because we use a fixed header. 
So how can I fix this, that it will go to the absolute top of the page?

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I use version 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.1 and this is the content of the file skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/opcheckout_rwd.js:

```
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {
    // Adds class so that the page can be styled to only show the "Checkout Method" step
    if ((this.currentStep == 'login' || this.currentStep == 'billing') && section == 'billing') {
        $j('body').addClass('opc-has-progressed-from-login');
    }

    if (reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
    }
    this.currentStep = section;
    var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);

    // Scroll viewport to top of checkout steps for smaller viewports
    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: ' + bp.xsmall + 'px)')) {
        $j('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $j('#checkoutSteps').offset().top}, 800);
    }

    if (!reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.resetPreviousSteps();
    }
}
```

I don't have the problem that you describe. So I suggest you to change the package and use rwd (this should be the base package since Magento 1.9.1). You can start from this package and build a new theme.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use the One Page Checkout. I want to use the default step checkout.

Comment: I changed my answer, take a look now.